# Dax subtraction to find Idle Time

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

The image contains the column values like EmployeeName, RundateTime, Systemlock, SystemUnlockTime I wanted to subtract SystemLock and SystemUnlock values for each EmployeeName

[image: The image contains the column values like EmployeeName, RundateTime, Systemlock, SystemUnlockTime I wanted to subtract SystemLock and SystemUnlock values for each EmployeeName]

I initially tried filter and calculate the value i am unable do it can any one solve this problem of mine,

The data is in the format of

| EmployeeName | Date | SystemLock | SystemUnlock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 16-11-2023 | 8:45:00 | - |
| A | 16-11-2023 | - | 8:47:34 |

Comment: Your data structure needs to be cleaned up. You have multiple rows with different values for the same person (fragmented). Why is that?

Comment: Edit your question to show your data as text which can be copy/pasted. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).